# SAML trusted certificate

Tags: java, keytool, spring-saml, opensaml, java-security

I'm using opensaml 2.6.1 and spring-security-saml2-core 1.0.1 in some project to enable SSO.
I'm using a self signed certificate for encryption and signature.

When my service provider received the SAML response, I'm getting the following error:

```
DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator] Creating XMLSignature object
DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator] Validating signature with signature algorithm URI: http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha512
DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator] Validation credential key algorithm 'RSA', key instance class 'sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl'
DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator] Signature validated with key from supplied credential
DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine] Signature validation using candidate credential was successful
DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine] Successfully verified signature using KeyInfo-derived credential
DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine] Attempting to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential
DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine] Failed to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential
DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine] Failed to verify signature and/or establish trust using any KeyInfo-derived credentials
DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine] Attempting to verify signature using trusted credentials
DEBUG [org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine] Failed to verify signature using either KeyInfo-derived or directly trusted credentials
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl] Validation of authentication statement in assertion failed, skipping
org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException: Signature is not trusted or invalid
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.verifySignature(AbstractProfileBase.java:272)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertionSignature(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:419)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:292)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
    at
```

What i have understand from exception messageis :

- the signature verification is succesful
- There is an issue when trusting my certificat
  Are my assupmtions corrects?

I have imported my self signed certificate to my keystore (cacerts store in the JVM) using the following command:

```
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts  -file "myCcert.crt" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -alias test
```

Dosen't this command import my certif and mark it as trusted by java?

Another thing,can java trust a self signed signature or I must get a certificate validate by a CA to pass the validation?

Comment: Yes. Java can trust a self-signed cert.

Comment: Thanks anacron,
So what can be the cause of this exception?

Comment: If you are trying to implement SSL, then you will need a key store. `cacerts` is a trust store not a key store. It works fine if you want to access some one else's SSL site. But if you are setting up SSL on your site, then you'll need a different keystore.

Comment: I'm using this certification for signature/validation.
My certification is added to cacerts, why than I'm still getting this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Spring SAML doesn't use cacerts for trust verification, but its dedicated keystore (samlKeystore.jks in the sample application). Please read the Spring SAML manual's chapter about certificate management for details.